# неправильная установка id spring boot postgree jpa

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, boot

После сохранения конкретного id , он добавляется в конец списка БД, был 43 например а добавился после 50. 
Вот мой код.
package com.countries.entities;

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Country {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String name;
private String capital;

public Country() {
}

public Country(String name, String capital) {
    this.name = name;
    this.capital = capital;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCapital() {
    return capital;
}

public void setCapital(String capital) {
    this.capital = capital;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Country{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", capital='" + capital + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
@Controller
public class CountryController {

@Autowired
CountryRepository countryRepository;

@GetMapping("/")
public String showPage(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page) {
    model.addAttribute("data",
            countryRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, 4)));
    model.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
    return "index";
}

@PostMapping("/save")
public String save(Country country) {
    countryRepository.save(country);
    return "redirect:/";
}

@GetMapping("/delete")
public String deleteCountry(long id) {
    countryRepository.deleteById(id);
    return "redirect:/";
}

@GetMapping("/findOne")
@ResponseBody
public Country findOne(long id) {
    return countryRepository.findById(id).get();
}
```

}

Comment: Вопрос не очень понятен. Попробуйте подробнее описать что вы делаете, что ожидаете получить и что получаете. В данный момент могу лишь предположить, что вы удаляете что-то из БД и потом удивляетесь, что новые записи не получают ID удалённых ранее. Если вы об этом - то так и должно быть.

Comment: Если речь о синтетическом автоинкрементном первичном ключе таблицы - то это абсолютно правильно. Более того, непонятно, зачем вообще смотреть на его значение? есть только одна цель, ради которой может потребоваться его смотреть - это убедиться, что пока не грозит переполнение для типа данных этого поля. Всё. Любые другие основания увидеть это значение есть ошибка и непонимание сути функционирования БД.

Comment: я использую метод save в качестве апдейта нужного мне поля, нужное id сохраняется, но поле заново перезаписывается в конец, раньше вроде так не работало

Comment: Для начала сделайте два разных метода save и update. Используйте их по назначению. Думаю проблема решится сама собой.